# Place item number inside math mode

Tags: spacing, align, vertical-alignment, enumitem

In the following excerpt of a write-up, I would like to have the `item` number `(i)` at the same line as the first equation that follows it, to avoid the empty first line. I cannot find any way to manually do this correctly.

Thanks for any idea you can provide.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item \begin{alignat*}{2}
            \langle a_0, z \rangle &> 0, \ldots, \langle a_q, z \rangle &&> 0, \\
            \langle c_1, z \rangle &\geq 0, \ldots, \langle c_r, z \rangle &&\geq 0, 
            \shortintertext{and}
            \langle b_1, z \rangle &= 0, \ldots, \langle b_p, z \rangle &&= 0,
        \end{alignat*}
        has a solution,
        \item[or]
        \item There exist scalars $\alpha_0, \ldots,\alpha_q$, $\gamma_1, \ldots,\gamma_r$, and $\beta_1, \ldots,\beta_p$, not all zero, satisfying
        \begin{equation*}
            \begin{gathered}
                \alpha_0 a_0 + \dots + \alpha_q a_q + \gamma_1 c_1 + \dots + \gamma_r c_r + \beta_1 b_1 + \dots + \beta_p b_p = 0, \\
                \alpha_i \geq 0, \; i = 0,\ldots,q, \\
                \gamma_i \geq 0, \; i = 1,\ldots,r,
            \end{gathered}
        \end{equation*}
        but never both.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\item` doesn't technically set the numbering in the list on the page until there is something set for the item. So, I would insert an `\mbox{}`, followed by a forced move into vertical mode (via `\par`), and then adjust the vertical spacing - a combination of `\parskip` (due to `\par`), `\baselineskip` (to jump up full lines vertically) and `\abovedisplayskip` (what is inserted above a display that doesn't have a large line-ending width for the paragraph above).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item \mbox{} \par
  \vspace{\dimexpr-2\baselineskip-\parskip-\abovedisplayskip}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    \langle a_0, z \rangle &> 0, \dots, \langle a_q, z \rangle    &&> 0, \\
    \langle c_1, z \rangle &\geq 0, \dots, \langle c_r, z \rangle &&\geq 0, 
  \shortintertext{and}
    \langle b_1, z \rangle &= 0, \dots, \langle b_p, z \rangle    &&= 0,
  \end{alignat*}
  has a solution,
  
  \item[or]
  
  \item
  There exist scalars $\alpha_0, \dots,\alpha_q$, $\gamma_1, \dots,\gamma_r$, and $\beta_1, \dots,\beta_p$, not all zero, satisfying
  \[
    \begin{gathered}
      \alpha_0 a_0 + \dots + \alpha_q a_q + \gamma_1 c_1 + \dots + \gamma_r c_r + \beta_1 b_1 + \dots + \beta_p b_p = 0, \\
      \alpha_i \geq 0, \; i = 0, \dots, q, \\
      \gamma_i \geq 0, \; i = 1, \dots, r,
    \end{gathered}
  \]
  but never both.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note though that `\parskip` and `\abovedisplayskip` are both rubber lengths, and therefore this solution may need some tweaking depending on the placement on of the page.

Answer (score 2):

For the first `\item`, I suggest you use an `alignedat` environment, with `[t]` alignment, instead of an `alignedat*` environment. For the second `\item`, I'd use a single `gather*` environment instead of a nested `equation*`/`gathered` combination.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item Either\quad$\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
            \langle a_0, z \rangle &> 0, \dots, \langle a_q, z \rangle &&> 0, \\
            \langle c_1, z \rangle &\geq 0, \dots, \langle c_r, z \rangle &&\geq 0, \\
            \text{and\quad}& \\
            \langle b_1, z \rangle &= 0, \dots, \langle b_p, z \rangle &&= 0,
        \end{alignedat}$
        
        has a solution, or
        \item there exist scalars $\alpha_0, \dots,\alpha_q$, $\gamma_1, \dots,\gamma_r$, and $\beta_1, \dots,\beta_p$, not all zero, satisfying
        \begin{gather*}
                \alpha_0 a_0 + \dots + \alpha_q a_q + 
                \gamma_1 c_1 + \dots + \gamma_r c_r + 
                \beta_1  b_1 + \dots + \beta_p  b_p = 0, \\
                \alpha_i \geq 0, \quad i = 0,\ldots,q, \\
                \gamma_i \geq 0, \quad i = 1,\ldots,r,
        \end{gather*}
        but never both.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mico, for your solution; it makes sense.

Comment: Sure, thank you for the heads-up. I will review the different answers.